# add language to header using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, http, axios

I have been creating a web application using ReactJS and Symfony, I want to add a multi language functionality to my application. The problem is when I add locale to requests as a header parameter, I'm getting a `Failed to load response data`, also I see the message `Provisional headers are shown`

```
const instance = axios.create({
baseURL: 'myapp.com',
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json',
    locale: 'en'
}});
```

when I remove the parameter locale it work correctly and the request passed to the API and the worning message "Provisional headers are shown" disappear from the browser.

how can I solve the problem ?. Thanks.

Comment: Are any other error messages shown? This seems like the sort of thing that would trigger a CORS related error message.

Comment: Why are you setting a header called `local`? That isn't even a word used for language related things (like `locale`) and there's a perfectly good, standard `Accept-Language` request header!

Comment: I dont want to set Accept-Language, I want to add a new parameter locale to all requests. when I add it all request doesn't passed. then I see the message "Provisional headers are shown" in the browser (header section)

Comment: Leaving aside that it's *bizarre* to use a made up header instead of a standard one: You need to address my first comment.

Comment: @Quentin there aren't any other problem.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean you want to set the accept language?

```
headers: {
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;"
}
```

Comment: No, I want to add a new paramter locale to all requests as a header parameter

Comment: I just read your question again and Failed to load response data doesn't seems to be an error with your header, but the response from the server. What's the status code? is it 200?

Comment: the request doesn't passed

Comment: Then more information is needed, including the exact response. E.g. did the request go through?

Comment: the request doesn't passed, the API doesn't receive any call. the key of the problem is the message "Provisional headers are shown"

Comment: when I remove the parameter locale it work correctly and the request passed to the API and the worning message "Provisional headers are shown" disappear

Comment: You using chrome?

Comment: the same problem on chrome & firefox & Microsoft edge

Comment: Most likely the real problem with "locale" header in particular is CORS. The browser is blocking the request since "locale" is not whitelisted by the OPTIONS response. Just in case someone gets across this question still :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the locale to the list of parameters accepted in the allow_header section of the API and now it works.

```
allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'locale']
```